# regular expression to check ends with a digit

Tags: regex, parsing, logging

EDIT: Hi I want to parse this log

```
String log1 = "Yellow A  Yellow Flow Meter  -4363.00  ---> -4194.00 pulse" ;
```

I used this pattern

```
String maxPattern11 = "([\\w.*-?\\d.$]+)([\\s]+['--->'|'-->']+[\\s]+)([-?][\\d.]+\\s[\\w]+)";
```

For the string I want to parse like a series of words separated by white space and ends with a +ve or a -ve digit.

Please reply whats wrong in the pattern

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a difficult regular expression, here is another idea:

```
String[] words = logLine.split("\\s+");
int n = words.length;
if (n > 3 && words[n - 3].equals("--->")) {
}
```

It may be more code than the regular expression, but it is much easier to understand.